# XMLHttpRequest will not use HTTPS even with an absolute URL

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code and the associated error:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    product_prices = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", ("https://example.com/" + products), true);
            xhttp.send();
```

Error in chrome:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com/1_/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

XHR failed loading: GET "http://example.com/1_/".

XHR failed loading: GET "https://example.com/1_/".
```

The network section of the dev tools also shows that the correct https request was status:cancelled

If a relative url is used, the request is sent via http even though the page is using https.

The server is a django application and SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

Comment: Even though you are connecting to `https://example.com`, that domain uses `http`.

Comment: I do not understand, the url bar shows secure and our ssl cert is working.

Comment: From the error message it appears the request is being rerouted to a `/1_/` path, which is different than the request path of `/en/`.

Comment: @Brett DeWoody this was a mistake in copying and has been corrected